# Group by consider different number 01 and 1

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query which consider 01 and 1 are different.

Suppose this query : SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY numbers

It's give different 2 rows for 01 and 1

Result should be in 1 row because 01 and 1 are equal.

Comment: have you tried ```SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY CAST(numbers AS UNSIGNED)``` ?

Comment: What is the column definition? It must not be numeric, so using a CAST() to numeric like @Kristian said would be how to make them equivalent, as long as the data always contains only valid digits.

Answer (score 0):

If the column only contains numbers, you can `CAST` it into `UNSIGNED`:

```
SELECT CAST(numbers AS UNSIGNED) as numbers, count(*)
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY CAST(numbers AS UNSIGNED)
```

If you only want to consider `'1' = '01'` this can help:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN numbers = '01' then 1 else numbers end as numbers, count(*)
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN numbers = '01' then 1 else numbers end
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NqnOpEao)